# Decoding JSON Array of Objects in PHP, is it the back slashes?

Tags: php, jquery, json

So I'm posting an array of objects in a JSON string using javascript to a PHP script and I'm having real problems decoding it in the php.

My javascript is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "question_save.php",
    data: {myJson:  JSON.stringify(jsonArray)},
    success: function(data){

        alert(data);

    }
});
```

The string sent to the PHP looks like this:

```
[{"content":"Question text"},{"answerContent":"Some answer text","score":"234","responseChecked":0,"responseContent":""},{"answerContent":"","score":"0","responseChecked":0,"responseContent":""}]
```

If I echo $_POST['myJson'] I get this:

```
[{\"content\":\"Question text\"},{\"answerContent\":\"Some answer text\",\"score\":\"234\",\"responseChecked\":0,\"responseContent\":\"\"},{\"answerContent\":\"\",\"score\":\"0\",\"responseChecked\":0,\"responseContent\":\"\"}]
```

Yet when I want to decode the JSON and loop through it like this...

```
$json = $_POST['myJson'];
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as &$value) {
    echo("Hi there");
}
```

...I get this error:

```
Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/thecrime/public_html/test1/question_save.php on line 15
```

I really don't understand what silly mistake I'm making, is it something to do with the back slashes?

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks,
-Ben

Comment: print $data values and see what is the value for this variable after json_decode ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `stripslashes ( $string )` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

This should work

```
$json = $_POST['myJson'];
$json_string = stripslashes($json)
$data = json_decode($json_string, true);

// simple debug
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

---

However, as already pointed by the others, it's better to disable `magic_quotes_gpc`.

Open your `php.ini` file and search for this row:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = On
```

Set it to `Off` and restart the server.

Comment: Simone you are my savior and I love you. Thanks! :D

Comment: Although obviously a valid answer, this is fighting the symptoms instead of the cause: magic_quotes_gpc. Turn them off, and you'll never have to worry about stuff like this again.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)
Is better to disable this annoying old feature and forget those problems.
You can disabled following [these instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).